# How to handle ajax post request with node.js and without framworks?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

I'm practicing node js and ajax without any frameworks (like jquery, expressJS) by doing a simple app that gives information about a city's weather using openweatherapi.
Here is my code so far:
    app.js

```
    const http = require("http");
    const fs = require("fs");
    const path = require("path");
    const { parse } = require('querystring');


    const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    if(req.url === "/"){
         fs.readFile("index.html", "UTF-8", function(err, data){
         res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
         res.end(data);
         });
     }else if(req.url === "/public/styles.css"){
         var cssPath = path.join(__dirname + req.url);
         var cssFileStream = fs.createReadStream(cssPath, "UTF-8");
         res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/css"});
         cssFileStream.pipe(res);
     }else if(req.url === "/public/main.js"){
         var jsFileStream = fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/${req.url}`, "UTF-8");
         res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/js"});
         jsFileStream.pipe(res);
     }else if(req.url === "/favicon.ico"){
         res.statusCode=204;
         res.end();
    };
     if(req.url ==="/"&&req.method==="POST"){
         let body = "";
         req.on('data', chunk=>{
             body += chunk.toString();
         });
         req.on("end", ()=>{
             parse(body);
         });
         console.log(body);
     };

  });

  var PORT = process.env.port || 3000;
  server.listen(PORT);
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Weather Application</title>
        <link href="./public/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="./public/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="weather-div">
            <h1> Search for weather information of a city</h1>
            <form method="post" action="/">
            <input class="locationName" id="cityName" name="city" type="text" placeholder="City" required/>
            <input class="locationName" id="countryName" name="city" type="text" placeholder="Country"/>
            </form>
            <button id="submitBtn" type="submit">Search Weather</button>
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
function getData(){
    var city = document.getElementById('cityName');
    var country = document.getElementById('countryName');

    if(city.value.length>0){
    const apiKey = "APIKey";
    const apiUrl =  "http://api.openweathermap.org";

    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        };
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "app.js",true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(`city=${city}&country=${country}`);
    };
};

window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", getData, false);
};
```

So what i want to do is to send the city name of the input using ajax because i tried with a simple form and a submit button, but it keeps on refreshing the page. I don't want it. And I want a receive the data in app.js to parse it and filter its code with a json file of cities and then return it to main.js to send an api call to openweathermap.
Fortunately i know how to do the simple stuff: the parsing and the api call. But all the other stuff i have totally no idea. when i search about it, I only find a solution using jquery or express, but I don't want that, i want pure javascript to get better.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First argument in an event callback is the event object. For a form, to prevent the default browser behavior of refreshing or navigating to the action page, use `e.preventDefault()`.

So the click event that executes callback getData would look like:

```
function getData(e){ // First argument of an event callback is the event
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default button type submit behavior    

    var city = document.getElementById('cityName');
    var country = document.getElementById('countryName');

    if(city.value.length>0){
    const apiKey = "APIKey";
    const apiUrl =  "http://api.openweathermap.org";

    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        };
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "app.js",true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(`city=${city}&country=${country}`);
    };
};
```

Comment: And I have to put my inputs in a form with action="/" and method="post"?

Comment: Programming there are multiple ways to do something. With current markup and attributes looks like all needs to happen to append your button element as a child of the `<form>` element, like `<form> <!-- some other elements.. --> <button id="submitBtn" type="submit">Search Weather</button>` so that the submit button is owned, or "assigned" if you will, to that form.

Comment: If i understand well, it's not necessaty to put it  in a form tag.

Comment: Yes, multiple ways to do this

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.